# Запретить удалять, изменять и т.д чужие комментарии Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

Есть пользователь с правами на редактирование комментов, назовем его "comm_moderator". Как запретить пользователям с этими правами удалять, отправлять в спам, изменять, отклонять и тд чужие комменты кроме своих. Т.е. что бы он мог только ответить или одобрить коммент, но не мог ни чего другого если не он автор коммента.

Answer (score 1):

Может кому то будет полезно. Нашел такую функцию на англоязычном сайте.

```
add_filter('comment_row_actions', 'remove_comment_row_actions');
function remove_comment_row_actions($actions) {
    global $user_ID, $comment;  
    if( $comment->user_id != $user_ID ){
        unset($actions['quickedit']);
        unset($actions['edit']);
        unset($actions['spam']);
        unset($actions['trash']);
    }
    return $actions;
}
```

Ну и плюс проверка на нужного пользователя. Все работает. Всем спасибо!